# Redmine installation : Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, redmine

I finish all the installtion step for redmine and configure apache

```
sree@sree:/usr/share/redmine$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.13
sree@sree:/usr/share/redmine$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
sree@sree:/usr/share/redmine$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.3.5
```

while runing but localhost/redmine i am getting error as shown below 
[image]!

---

As ber the error message "**Error message:
    Redmine requires Bundler 1.0.21 (you're using 1.0.15). Please install a newer version with `gem install bundler`.** "i install bundler version

```
 sree@sree:/$ sudo gem install bundler -v 1.0.21
    Successfully installed bundler-1.0.21
```

still getting the same error

```
***************************************************************************
sree@sree:/$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
```

---

```
Gem.lock
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
    activesupport (3.2.13)
      i18n (= 0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.0)
    capybara (2.0.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
      xpath (~> 1.0.0)
    childprocess (0.3.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    ffi (1.9.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.3)
      railties (>= 3.1.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.8.0)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    metaclass (0.0.1)
    mime-types (1.24)
    mocha (0.13.3)
      metaclass (~> 0.0.1)
    multi_json (1.7.9)
    mysql2 (0.3.13)
    net-ldap (0.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.5.10)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-openid (1.3.1)
      rack (>= 1.1.0)
      ruby-openid (>= 2.1.8)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.13)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activerecord (= 3.2.13)
      activeresource (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.13)
    railties (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rmagick (2.13.2)
    ruby-openid (2.2.3)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    selenium-webdriver (2.35.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    shoulda (3.3.2)
      shoulda-context (~> 1.0.1)
      shoulda-matchers (~> 1.4.1)
    shoulda-context (1.0.2)
    shoulda-matchers (1.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    xpath (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)
    yard (0.8.7)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord-jdbc-adapter (= 1.2.5)
  activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
  builder (= 3.0.0)
  capybara (~> 2.0.0)
  coderay (~> 1.0.9)
  fastercsv (~> 1.5.0)
  i18n (~> 0.6.0)
  jquery-rails (~> 2.0.2)
  mocha (~> 0.13.3)
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.11)
  net-ldap (~> 0.3.1)
  nokogiri (< 1.6.0)
  rack-openid
  rails (= 3.2.13)
  rdoc (>= 2.4.2)
  rmagick (>= 2.0.0)
  ruby-openid (~> 2.2.3)
  shoulda (~> 3.3.2)
  yard


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhcpo.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference - http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html
Following the steps

1  Install apache with Phusion Passenger:

```
user@user:~gem install passenger
```

1. add the RubyGems bin directory to your $PATH

   a.

   /etc/bash.bashrc-  write in end export  PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin

   b.  Run `export  PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin`
2. `passenger-install-apache2-module`

a.  Follow the instruction as output 
i.   Create two files inside /etc/apache2/mods-available/
              1.    passenger.load
    LoadModule passenger_module /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.14/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so

passenger.conf

PassengerDefaultRuby /home/user/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby
PassengerRoot /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.14

1. user@user:~passenger-memory-stats

**Apache configuration**

1. user@user:~ln –s /home/user/redmine-2.3/public /var/www/redmine
2. user@user:~sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

   RailsEnv development
   RackBaseURI /redmine

   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow, deny
    Allow from all
     
    
      SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT “/redmine”

   `user@user:~sudo service apache2 restart

   ```
   user@user:~firefox http://localhost/redmine`
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove old version of bundler.

Comment: yes removed now only have bundler-1.3.5 still getting the error dont know from where 1.0.15 ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

and remove all bundler versions what you have.

After this, install bundler again.

```
gem install bundler -v 1.0.21
```

I hope this works to you.

Comment: no hope  still getting the same error The application has exited during startup (i.e. during the evaluation of config/environment.rb). The error message can be found below. To solve this problem, please follow any instructions in the error message.

Error message:
    Redmine requires Bundler 1.0.21 (you're using 1.0.15). Please install a newer version with `gem install bundler`. 
Application root:
    /usr/share/redmine

Comment: how to fine where is bundler  1.0.15 reference ?

Comment: In redmine you can find the reference for bundler 1.0.21 inside the file preinitializer.rb: 'if Gem::Version.new(Bundler::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new("1.0.21")'.

Maybe if you change this if to 1.0.15 can works!

Comment: i install a fresh application and it is working fine with command:ruby script/rails server webrick -e production at localhost:3000
i find out that the problem is with apache server configuration can you suggest any help on this