# Ruby：passenger + nginx : How to install redmine

Tags: nginx, passenger, ubuntu-14.04, redmine

I try to install Redmine 3.0.4 in Ubuntu. I follow this guide:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu

but it still can not get it to work.

There is an error when I execute `bundle install`:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/hnb/redmine# bundle install
Redmine requires Bundler 1.5.0 or higher (you're using 1.3.5).
Please update with 'gem update bundler'.
```

I tried to perform the steps described in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397506/redmine-installation-error) but didn't not work.

Comment: And as you run the command indicated in the error message, i.e. `gem update bundler`, what was the result?

Answer (score 1):

Finally , I install the install package - bitnami Redmine.
Here is the link ： https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine.